# Javascript sqlite3 string not appending

Tags: javascript, sqlite

When I query my SQLite Database in `db.each` the string wont append using the addition operator

```
var messages = "Global Message History: \n\n";

db.each(sql, [Article], (err, row) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  console.log(`[${row.message_timestamp}] <@${row.msg_id}> in #${row.channel_name} on Server "${row.server_name}": ${row.message_content}`); //Outputs all messages
  messages += `[${row.message_timestamp}] <@${row.msg_id}> in #${row.channel_name} on Server "${row.server_name}": ${row.message_content}\n`; // Doesn't work

});

sendMsg(messages);
```

`sendMsg();` should only be executed once with all the messages but it doesnt seem to work and the output is only `Global Message History: \n\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once this method is asynchronous, you should call `sendMsg()` in `complete` argument of [`db.each`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete) as:

```
var messages = "Global Message History: \n\n";

db.each(sql, [Article], (err, row) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  console.log(`[${row.message_timestamp}] <@${row.msg_id}> in #${row.channel_name} on Server "${row.server_name}": ${row.message_content}`); //Outputs all messages
  messages += `[${row.message_timestamp}] <@${row.msg_id}> in #${row.channel_name} on Server "${row.server_name}": ${row.message_content}\n`; // Doesn't work
}, function(){ sendMsg(messages) });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome that works, didn't knew this exist. Thanks for helping me out!